# FutureWarning get_params from scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, warnings

I am getting the warning

```
File "[...]\lib\threading.py", line 890, in _bootstrap
  self._bootstrap_inner()
File "[...]\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
  self.run()
File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.1.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py", line 216, in run
  self._on_run()
File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.1.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_console_commands.py", line 30, in _on_run
  values.append(pydevd_thrift.var_to_struct(var_obj, name, evaluate_full_value=True))
File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.1.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_thrift.py", line 305, in var_to_struct
  value = format % v
File "[...]\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 263, in __repr__
  repr_ = pp.pformat(self)
File "[...]\lib\pprint.py", line 153, in pformat
  self._format(object, sio, 0, 0, {}, 0)
File "[...]\lib\pprint.py", line 170, in _format
  rep = self._repr(object, context, level)
File "[...]\lib\pprint.py", line 404, in _repr
  repr, readable, recursive = self.format(object, context.copy(),
File "[...]\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_pprint.py", line 169, in format
  return _safe_repr(object, context, maxlevels, level,
File "[...]\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_pprint.py", line 415, in _safe_repr
  params = object.get_params(deep=False)
File "[...]\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 193, in get_params
  warnings.warn('From version 0.24, get_params will raise an '
File "[...]\lib\warnings.py", line 109, in _showwarnmsg
  sw(msg.message, msg.category, msg.filename, msg.lineno,
File "<input>", line 59, in warn_with_traceback
[...]\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:193: FutureWarning: From version 0.24, get_params will raise an AttributeError if a parameter cannot be retrieved as an instance attribute. Previously it would return None.
warnings.warn('From version 0.24, get_params will raise an '
```

when trying to use sklearn. I have no idea how to find out how to solve this. Obviously this is little information for you, but I do not even know where to begin to track down the issue.

The only thing that I could add is that it happens when I am trying to instantiate a class I wrote that inherits from [CalibratedClassifierCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.calibration.CalibratedClassifierCV.html).

How can I approach this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think, I was able to find the answer by luck. As described in scikit-learn's [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/develop.html#instantiation), the initialization *must* look like

```
def __init__(self, param1=1, param2=2):
    self.param1 = param1
    self.param2 = param2
```

The mistake I did, was to write something like

```
def __init__(self, param1=1, param2=2):
    self.param1 = param1
    self.param2_ = param2
```

Note the underscore. This must be avoided, because it will mess with the methods `set_params` and `get_params`. Indeed, my warning originated from the later.

Additionally the trailing underscore is for [estimated attributes](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/develop.html#estimated-attributes):

> Attributes that have been estimated from the data must always have a name ending with trailing underscore, for example the coefficients of some regression estimator would be stored in a coef_ attribute after fit has been called.
>
> The estimated attributes are expected to be overridden when you call fit a second time.

Comment: U saved my life with this post!

Comment: @dpendi: I am very glad, I could be of help :-). Leave an upvote for the question as well if you think it helped.